# SuiteScript: JSDoc for function from higher scope (define)

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

SuiteScript (2.x) wraps the script code in `define` function.

```js
define(['N/task'], (task) => {
    // my code
});
```

In my IDE (VSCode) is `define` underlined and shows following tooltip `Cannot find name 'define'.` It's because `define()` comes from higher scope which my IDE is not aware of.

How to write JSDoc to tell my IDE this function definition is somewhere else and specify accepted params and returned value?

```js
/**
 * @param {String[]} modulePaths - Module Paths
 * @param {Function} callback - Callback function
 * @returns {Object} - Object with endpoints
 */
```

Is this even possible using JSDoc? Or should I just ignore this one error?

Comment: this has nothing to do with SuiteScript. It's a question about how to set up VSCode